# How can I make sense of a Method to create a pdf? C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, reflector

I was handed this Method taken from .NET Reflector conversion from a .wsp and no documentation.  The app's purpose is to create a signable .pdf form. Cannot use 3rd party or even open source, so iTextSharp, PDFSharp, & the like are not options, and I'm a newbie doing my best to raise my learning curve.

I have added references/using directives to the .cs "Method" file to re-create the aspx.cs file.  The last error I have remaining is:
'The type or namespace name 'Doc' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

I cannot find a reference that gets 'Doc' to work anywhere.  'Document' and 'Word' are the two closest things I can find online to help, but have not been any help to increase my understanding.
Does this method look familiar to anyone?

```
protected void Create_PDF()
{
    Doc doc = new Doc();
    Doc doc2 = new Doc();
    doc2.Read(base.Server.MapPath(@"images\form_name.pdf"));
    int num = doc2.get_PageCount();
    Doc doc3 = new Doc();
    doc3.set_FontSize(10);
    doc3.get_MediaBox().set_String(doc2.get_MediaBox().get_String());
    doc3.get_Rect().Magnify(0.5, 0.5);
    doc3.get_Rect().Inset(10.0, 10.0);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String(doc3.get_MediaBox().get_String());
    doc3.AddImageDoc(doc2, 1, null);
    doc3.FrameRect();
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,570,230,590");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_1);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("250,570,420,590");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_2);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("430,570, 570, 590");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_3);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,540,170,555");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_4);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("170,540,570,555");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_5);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,500, 230, 515");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_6);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("235,500,360,515");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_7);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("370,500, 570, 515");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_8);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,465,305,485");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_9);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("310,465, 570,485");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_10);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,440,305,453");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_11);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("310,440, 570, 453");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_12);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("39,412, 51, 425");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[0]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("39,402, 51, 413");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[1]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("39,390, 51, 401");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[2]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("39,378, 51, 389");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[3]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("200,412, 212, 425");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[4]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("200,402, 212, 413");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[5]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("200,390, 212, 401");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[6]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("399,412, 410, 425");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[7]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("399,402, 410, 413");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[8]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("399,390, 410, 401");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_13[9]);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,260,570,368");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_14);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,200,570,235");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_15);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,120,300,140");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_16);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("310,120,570,140");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_17);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("362,71,468,90");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_18);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("485,71,570,90");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_19);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("40,40,210,60");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_20);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("235,40,390,60");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_21);
    doc3.get_Rect().set_String("400,40,570,60");
    doc3.AddHtml(this.str_22);
    this.Ser = this.sID.ToString();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.strConnString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cmdText = "insert into Image (Ser,ImageData) values(@Ser, @ImageData)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                doc3.Save(stream);
                byte[] data = doc3.GetData();
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ser", this.Ser));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", data));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException exception)
        {
            if (string.Compare(exception.Message.ToString().Substring(0, 0x18), "Violation of PRIMARY KEY") == 0)
            {
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("delete from image where ser = '" + this.Ser + "'", connection);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                try
                {
                    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc3.Clear();
}
```

//Gratefully yours,
//RN

Comment: it will be in the same project as the source of this code most likely

Comment: @Sayse:Those were not sufficient to avoid the "namespace name 'Doc' could not be found ".  <br/> When the gent handed me the methods for the source code that he got from the dll using .NET Reflector, he went on vacation.  I've downloaded .NET Reflector to my dev machine and will figure out how to extract Methods/Code-behind myself.  .NET Reflector seems a bit confusing to me (a newcomer) within Visual Studio 2010 or as Desktop app.  All suggestions welcome.

Comment: My point is that Stack Overflow won't be able to help you on this occasion as Doc will be a class within the project you found that from, your best bet may be to look if any of the other methods call a `doc` type